# UFW stopping FTP directory list

Tags: ufw, vsftpd

I have multiple users for my vsftpd instance that users can connect to.

User1 home directory: /ftp/user1 - works fine
User2 home directory: /ftp/user2 - works fine
User3 home directory: /ftp - works fine, this user is in charge of managing files for other users
user4(me) home directory /var/www/html - "failed to retrieve directory listing" with UFW enabled.

user4 is owner of /var/ww/html and all contents.

Filezilla log:

```
Status: Connecting to [ipaddress]:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (ip,ip,ip,ip,159,151).
Command:    LIST
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

With UFW disabled, the connection works as expected.

I had much more rules, but I broke something. I reset iptables, then cleared the ufw rules, and set up this.

I have 2 adaptors in this machine, one connecting to my private network, one is public facing if that matters.

```
default deny incoming
default allow outgoing

ufw status:
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       [lanip]/24
5222                       ALLOW       [lanip]/24
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere
5269                       ALLOW       [lanip]/24
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Secure              ALLOW       Anywhere
```

Am I missing rules for passive ports?

Answer (score 3):

Switching the ftp client to active mode worked, so it must be passive ports.

Looks like I need to edit /etc/vsftpd.conf:

```
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=10100
pasv_max_port=10110
```

then:

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
sudo ufw allow from any to any proto tcp port 10100:10110
```

EDIT: solved, this did the trick. I am going to leave this since I couldn't find good answers, hopefully I can help the next guy

Comment: this definitely helped me. Thank you